# TaxonomyWebTaggingControl Not Showing Up on Page

Tags: 2010, development, managed-metadata, taxonomy, application-pages

I am attempting to use a Taxonomy Picker Control (TaxonomyWebTaggingControl) on an Application Page based on the term set configured for a User Profile property.  In this scenario, I have set the Ask Me About field to use a Term Set in the User Profile Service Application.  When editing a user profile through the My Site or Central Admin, the field correctly displays as a Taxonomy Picker and allows me to select values from the Term Set.

In a new Application Page, I have registered the tag prefix:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And in the content I have added the control:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl id="ngAskMeAbout" runat="server" />
```

In the Page_Load, I am first obtaining the term set from the User Profile property and then using it to get the term set from the Taxonomy Session:

```
var site = SPContext.Current.Site;
var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
var configMgr = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);
var propertyMgr = configMgr.ProfilePropertyManager;
var corePropertyMgr = propertyMgr.GetCoreProperties();

var askMeAbout = corePropertyMgr.GetPropertyByName("SPS-Responsibility");

var termSet = askMeAbout.TermSet;

ngAskMeAbout.Disabled = false;
ngAskMeAbout.Enabled = true;
ngAskMeAbout.Visible = true;

var taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
var termStoreId = termSet.TermStore.Id;
var termGroupId = termSet.Group.Id;
var termSetId = termSet.Id;

ngAskMeAbout.SspId.Add(termStoreId);
ngAskMeAbout.GroupId = termGroupId;
ngAskMeAbout.TermSetId.Add(termSetId);

ngAskMeAbout.AllowFillIn = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsMulti = true;
ngAskMeAbout.IsAddTerms = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsDisplayPickerButton = true;
ngAskMeAbout.IsIncludeTermSetName = true;
ngAskMeAbout.IsUseCommaAsDelimiter = false;
ngAskMeAbout.Language = taxonomySession.TermStores[termStoreId].DefaultLanguage;
ngAskMeAbout.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
ngAskMeAbout.ExcludeKeyword = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsIgnoreFormatting = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsIncludeDeprecated = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsIncludePathData = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsIncludeUnavailable = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsSpanTermSets = false;
ngAskMeAbout.IsSpanTermStores = false;
```

When I try running this, nothing renders on the page.  I have debugged/stepped through the code to verify all the IDs are getting set properly and nothing generates an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: This code does work in a web part, however it simply does not display when displayed in an application page (in the layouts folder).  Need to figure out why...

Comment: Update 2: I have narrowed this down to an issue with the My Site host.  If I view the application page from elsewhere on my SharePoint site, it works fine.  However, when viewing it within the My Site host (http:// localhost /my/_layouts/...) it does not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did end up discovering the cause of the issue, however I think it is more of a bug in SharePoint:

When the solution is deployed as a Web feature to the My Site web, it causes the error to occur.  If I change the solution to be a Site feature and deploy it to the My Site Site Collection, the error does not occur.

Comment: I am getting the same issue even if I deploy the feature as Site feature.. Do you have any idea? then please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Left Navigation control calls a JavaScript function called "HideQuickLaunchMenu()".  For whatever reason, that function is undefined when it is called from my application page.  And thus it breaks the JavaScript for the taxonomy control.  As a remedy for my page, I added a blank function with the same name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideQuickLaunchMenu() {
    }
</script>
```

Doing this made the taxonomy control work properly again.  That function probably exists in one of the SharePoint JavaScript files (not in Core.js or SP.js, checked those), however I was unable to find it.  The code above works for me, so I will just go with that.